# Persistent "undefined reference to dladdr" linking error even when including -ldl (g++)

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, linker

No matter what I do I seem to be getting a "undefined reference to dladdr" linking error when compiling the following minimal program (on Ubuntu linux 18.04 with gcc 7.5.0)

```
g++ -o test src/main.cpp -I/opt/netgen/include -L/opt/netgen/lib -lnglib -pthread -ldl
```

- 

```
#include<iostream>
namespace nglib {
#include <nglib.h>
}
int main()
{
  nglib::Ng_Init();
  nglib::Ng_Exit();
}
```

I have tried to put -ldl in every position but the issue remains. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What is the output of this command? "whereis libdl"

Comment: The output is: libdl: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so and I get no error linking about missing libraries, just undefined reference

Comment: Okay, 2 things come to my mind.
Check what is the default search path for the linker. It could be missing the libdl paths. In that case try manually giving the path for your libdl directory.
Or, the glibc version you have may not have "dladdr" defined. BTW I copied this sample and compiled and linked successfully in my machine without this error.

Comment: Yes, very odd, thanks for confirming it should work.